# How to set default for the foreignkey when using a form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, foreign-keys, django-viewflow

Scenario: I want to make an app that has servers(500+) as a model and another model that has posts as a foreign key to the server model to log what we did on each server.So as I said I have two models the server and the posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do approach this is you can remove the `cluster_code` altogether in your form:

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Post
        fields = ['name','time','cluster_log']
```

and just add it to the post before saving to the database:

```
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.cluster_code = cluster_code
            post.save()
            redirect('view-post')
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you pass the cluster_code to forms, you can write a **init** method in your PostForm where you can save the value.